# Should I use my phone or a WIFI router to get WIFI?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a WIFI router with a SIM card and a phone where two SIM-cards can be placed. Today I put my wifi sim-card into my mobile phone and started a hotspot to watch netflix on my television, do video conferences and use my laptop for normal use. 
I think of keeping that up, with the advantage that I have unlimited WIFI always with me, especially on holidays and can also give this WIFI to others through my hotspot wherever I am.

So is there any important technical detail, that I am forgetting here, why that isn't a brilliant idea? Security of hotspot is not that big of a problem to me, as I can turn it off in public whenever I want. The last hours, I noticed no differences in internet speed, only that the video quality on Netflix was a littler lower, and that it uses a lot of battery on my phone. Are there any other important problems I could face with that option?

Answer (score 1):

If you go outside of your country for a holiday, you could pay a lot for internet use, so you have to keep that in mind.

That said, the only problem you may have, is that when you have a hotspot setup and you get a call, the hotspot may temporarily loose connection. In addition, you are draining your battery of your phone faster with a hotspot always on, and lastly, but this should not be a problem, you cannot connect to WiFi if you are running a hotspot, so if you forget to turn off the hotspot, you will keep consuming mobile data, which, at some point, you will start to pay for.

A 4G wifi router do exist in small packages too, but in the end it is up to you.

Comment: Good answer. Another this g to point out is that routers can have better antennas / external aerials, so can in some cases provide better signal.

Comment: @davidgo I agree with your point, but it is such common knowledge that I'm fairly sure this is not going to be an issue, or the OP would not even have considered using wifi all the time.

Answer (score 0):

What about the cost of replacing each device? Cheaper to replace WiFi router or phone? I think it is cheaper to replace router.

By the way, it is not a either or question. When you use at home, use router. If you go outside and need data, take the Sim card out and place inside the phone. Then you have the best of both world.